# Get Last N minutes records Dynamodb Streams

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am using dynamodb to create aggregation reports. My program woud trigger every 10 minutes get the records from dynamodb streams written in the last 10 minutes and create aggregate reports. I would like to know how to get this done using python and boto3. I was trying if there is a time parameter in get_shard_iterator but there is none. I need to get the shard_iterator based on the creation date. Is there another way to get this done.

Comment: DynamoDB streams are sharded based on the primary keys, not timestamp, so theres no 'built-in' way to do this.